# How to query the `jump condition ` table data out using Capsule and MySQL two ways?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables like below:

1） tblaffiliatesaccounts

```
mysql> select * from tblaffiliatesaccounts limit 12;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+
| id | affiliateid | relid | lastpaid   |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+
|  1 |           2 |   444 | 2019-11-01 |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+
```

`affiliateid`: affiliate ID，
`relid`: product id
`lastpaid`: lastest paid date

2）tblaffiliatespending

```
mysql> select * from tblaffiliatespending limit 12;
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
| id | affaccid | amount | clearingdate |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
|  1 |        1 |   0.03 | 2019-12-01   |
+----+----------+--------+--------------+
```

affaccid: this is ID value of `tblaffiliatesaccounts`

and now I know the `affiliateid=2`, I want to queryout all the `tblaffiliatespending` rows meet it's affacc's `affiliateid=2` condition.

How to do with [Capsule](https://github.com/mannysoft/capsule)?  and MySQL cli commnad?  I want to know the two ways to compare.

I only know how to query in one table.

Capsule is a simple wrapper package for the Laravel packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your exact struggle is, but I believe you need something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblaffiliatespending s
INNER JOIN tblaffiliatesaccounts a ON (a.id = s.affaccid AND a.affiliateid = 2);
```

As for using `Capsule`, I believe this should work:

```
Capsule\DB::table('tblaffiliatespending s')->select('*')->join('tblaffiliatesaccounts a', 'a.id', '=', 's.affaccid')->where("a.affiliateid", "2")->get();
```

Disclaimer: I have never used Capsule and I am referring to an outdated documentation. I am not sure the Capsule query will work, but by all means it should. If there are an problems with it, leave me a comment. Also keep in mind the MySQL query is better and will work faster in most cases as the condition is in the join. I do not know how is the right way to do that in Capsule, so I opted for a where clause instead.

Let me know if you have any other questions.